# How do i send a timed notification to a user with django?

Tags: python, django, notifications

I am building a hotel management system with django. I want to implement a functionality that sends the user(guest in this case) a notification 6 hours before their reservation expires asking them if they want to renew.

I have looked into some ways to do this like django-mails, channels and cron but they all do not seem to be able to do this or maybe I don't just know how to manipulate them well enough. Nevertheless, here is what I tried with cron:

notification/cron.py

```
class SendRenewalNotification(CronJobBase):
    RUN_EVERY_MINS = 60  # Run the cron job every hour

    schedule = Schedule(run_every_mins=RUN_EVERY_MINS)
    code = 'notification.send_renewal_notification'  

    def do(self):
        now = datetime.now()
        six_hours_later = now + timedelta(hours=6)

        reservations = Reservation.objects.filter(end_date__gte=now, end_date__lte=six_hours_later)

        for reservation in reservations:
            user = reservation.guest
            reservation_id = reservation.pk
            url = reverse('update_reservation', args=[reservation_id])
            view_reservations_url = reverse('view_reservations')

            subject = 'Renew Your Room Reservation'
            message = f'Dear {user.username}, your room reservation is ending soon. Would you like to renew it?'
            message += f' Click the link below to update your reservation:\n{url}'
            message += f'\n\nYou can also view all your reservations here: {view_reservations_url}'
            from_email = 'your_email@example.com'
            recipient_list = [user.email]

            send_mail(subject, message, from_email, recipient_list)
```

Comment: You likely want a message queue. Perhaps something like rabbitmq

Comment: You can try using django signals

Comment: @JonSG please do you have a link where i can read more on it

Comment: @Olasubomi I saw that somewhere as well but i did not want to go down another rabbot hole till i was sure that it would work...I'll look into it now

Comment: post your models.py and your view function